# gtools::mixedorder alters my dataframe

Tags: r

```
data = data.frame(v1 = c(2,"10+",3,4,5,6,7,8,9), v2 = c(15,30,12,59,44,24,67,19,35))

    data$v1

    [1] 2   10+ 3   4   5   6   7   8   9  
    Levels: 10+ 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

    mixedorder(data$v1)

    [1] 2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Notice the "10+" becomes "1". What's up with that?

Comment: You are confusing `mixedorder` with `mixedsort`.

Comment: According to another SO question, `mixedsort` is to be used when you want to sort the whole dataframe, instead of just reordering the values in a column. Is that not true? I tried `mixedsort` too, but my my other column (v2) stayed in the same order.

Comment: You should first try to understand the base function `order`. Apparently you want `data[mixedorder(data$v1),]`.

Comment: But that puts "10+" at the top, and I want it at the bottom. I tried `decreasing = TRUE`, but then the first row becomes "9" and I want it to be "2"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex like this to remove all non-number characters:

```
data[order(as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:]]+", "", data$v1))),]
#   v1 v2
#1   2 15
#3   3 12
#4   4 59
#5   5 44
#6   6 24
#7   7 67
#8   8 19
#9   9 35
#2 10+ 30
```